# Android, Detect when Keyboard is focused from ANY 3rd PARTY APPs

Tags: java, android, ios, keyboard, apk

I want to create an service or app which must perform following functionality :

1. It must be running in background and must be able to detect when there's focus on edittext (or say when keyboard pops-up)
2. Keyboard Pop-Up can be from any 3rd party app say by hike, whatsapp, or email clients, etc (NOTE: Not from my app. As my app will not have any things where user needs to type its just a setting kind of app)

Example: I want to make a service say which will modify google keyboard predictions as I want, but user can use any keyboard app or any other apps.

NOTE: I don't want to create whole keyboard app and give that functionality, I want user must be able to use his/her own choice keyboard but get functionality as my own predictions instead of google predictions.

Comment: Have you tried to create at least some part of the application you want? What issues have you faced with?

Comment: @AlexPeshik Thanks for your reply.

Nope I haven't started yet. As I am least interested in making whole new keyboard. I want suggestions, like is it possible to do this kind of thing with app/service which should not be an keyboard app at last.